# awk csv quoted field need to capitalize each word

Tags: csv, awk

How can I do this using awk . I need each word in the double quoted and doted string to be capitalized...

Examples:

```
8,7,martin sanders, Executive director,,
9,8,bred simons,"manager, second career services",,
10,9,Kely bricks,ceo,,
...
```

the desired output should be like:

```
8,7,Martin Sanders, Executive Director,,
9,8,Bred Simons,"Manager, Second Career Services",,
10,9,Kely Bricks,Ceo,,
```

I run this code:

```
 awk -FS"\"" -v FPAT='([^, ]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")' '{OFS=","}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (substr($i, 1, 1) == "\"") {
        len = length($i)
        $i = toupper(substr($i, 2,len - 2))""tolower(substr($i, 2, len))} {print $i} }}
    '
```

```
9,8,Bred Simons, "manager, Second Career Services",,
```

I try to use FPAT but I really don't understand how it works...
but it was not enough. I realize that this is a simple question for experienced users, but I don't have much experience with awk. Please help

I read the explanation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

Comment: From what I can see, you need the first letter of **each** word to be capitalized

Comment: Correct. Actually, the problem is only with the field in double quotes.

Comment: `-FS"\""` should be `-v FS="\""` or `BEGIN { FS="\"" }`; then again, you want to use either `FS` (define the delimiter) or `FPAT` (define the field) but not both

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I know that these are the basics of awk, but I started using it only yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't capitalizing the first letter of all the words in the row do what you want?

```bash
awk '{
    s = $0;
    while (match(s,/[[:alpha:]]+/)) {
        printf("%s", \
            substr(s,1,RSTART-1) \
            toupper(substr(s,RSTART,1)) \   
            substr(s,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) \
        )
        s = substr(s,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print s
}'
```

```
8,7,Martin Sanders, Executive Director,,
9,8,Bred Simons,"Manager, Second Career Services",,
10,9,Kely Bricks,Ceo,,
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have GNU awk I assume you also have GNU sed so - using GNU sed for `-E`, `\w` and `\u`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\w)(\w*)/\u\1\2/g' file
8,7,Martin Sanders, Executive Director,,
9,8,Bred Simons,"Manager, Second Career Services",,
10,9,Kely Bricks,Ceo,,
```

or even just (as @sundeep points out in the comments):

```
sed 's/\<\w/\u&/g' file
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the `-u` in GNU sed

Comment: Can be simplified to `sed 's/\<\w/\u&/g'` .... also, `sed -E 's/\w+/\L\u&/g'` if words can have mixed case (ex: ceO --> Ceo)